# Separating php from html in foreach snippet

Tags: php

Edit: solution was to add the missing equal signs to echo out variable (i.e., <?=). See comments below.

Following this format :

```
<ul>
<?php foreach($foo as $bar): ?>
  <li> hi i'm <?=$bar;?> </li>
<? endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

I want to convert the following into a similar, more MVC format of separating html and php to avoid echoing html, but unable to figure out how.

Original working code:

```
<? $i = 1; $tabsuffix = strtolower($content['tabs'][0]['label']);
foreach($content['tabs'] as $key => $tab){$tabid=$tab['label'] . "-" . $tabsuffix;
   echo '<li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
   <button class="nav-link ' . ($i == 1 ? "active" : "") . ' blob" id="pills-' . $tabid . 
   '-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#pills-' . $tabid . '" type="button" 
   role="tab" aria-controls="pills-' . $tabid . '" aria-selected="true">
   <h2 class="h4">' . $tab["label"]. '</h2>
   </button></li>';
$i++;} ?>
```

Unsuccessful reformated version:

```
<?$i = 1; $tabsuffix = strtolower($content['tabs'][0]['label']);
 foreach($content['tabs'] as $key => $tab):
 $tabid=$tab['label'] . "-" . $tabsuffix; ?>
 <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
 <button class="nav-link <?= ($i == 1 ? "active" : "")?> blob" id="pills-<?$tabid?>-tab"
 data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#pills-<?$tabid?>" type="button" role="tab"
 aria-controls="pills-<?$tabid?>" aria-selected="true">
  <h2 class="h4"><?$tab["label"]?></h2>
 </button>
 </li>
 <?$i++; endforeach; ?>
```

Any suggestions would be appreciative.

Comment: Does something not work as intended? What is the problem?

Comment: For one, `<?$tabid?>` and `<?$tab["label"]?>` will do nothing useful

Comment: I noticed that you are using the wrong `shorthand echo`syntax tag. e.g `<? $tabid ?>` should be instead `<?= $tabid ?>`

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to add the the equal sign after the question mark. That fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the commentators who pointed out that I forgot the equal sign--for example, `<? $tabid ?>` should have been `<?= $tabid ?>`.

Correct version:

```
<? $i = 1;$tabsuffix = strtolower($content['tabs'][0]['label']);
   foreach($content['tabs'] as $key => $tab):
      $tabid=$tab['label'] . "-" . $tabsuffix; ?>
      <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
       <button class="nav-link <?= ($i == 1 ? "active" : "")?> blob" 
      id="pills-<?=$tabid?>-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs- 
      target="#pills-<?=$tabid?>" type="button" role="tab" aria- 
      controls="pills-<?=$tabid?>" aria-selected="true">
       <h2 class="h4"><?=$tab["label"]?></h2>
       </button>
       </li>
 <?$i++; endforeach; ?>
```